# Remove specific category from list in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

im using

```
<?php
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
        $cats .= $category->cat_name . ', ';
    }
    echo rtrim($cats, ', ');
?>
```

to display the category names of a post. How would i go about out removing a specific category from this list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested but something like this should work:

```
<?php
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) 
{
    if($category->cat_name == "category name")
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $cats .= $category->cat_name . ', ';
    }
}
echo rtrim($cats, ', ');
?>
```